# Выложить проект на веб-сервер

Tags: php, html, apache

Есть 5 файликов, один из них соответственно точка входа, есть веб сервер в локальной сети, как заставить веб сервер открывать этот проект?

Comment: Стоит уточнить что значит открывать? Запускать php-скрипт? Есть ли возможность скопировать файлы на машину с веб сервером?

Comment: какой сервер аз есмь?

Comment: apache веб сервер

Comment: @kb0 Да php скрипт, да доступ есть

Comment: Создать виртуальный хост в конфигах апача.